# Search database whilst filtering out posts that don't have images

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables, something like this (only posting relevant info):

```
USER:
-----
user_id

POST:
----
post_id
user_id

IMAGE:
----
image_id
post_id
```

What I am trying to do, is allow a user to search for posts, they can choose whether or not the post results include images or not.

So it'll be something like:

```
if ($images_selected) { $SQL_TO_FIND_POSTS_WITH_IMAGES; } else { $SQL_TO_FIND_POSTS_WITHOUT_IMAGES; }
```

Having a lot of trouble getting my head round how I will do this.

Cannot change any table structure as it must be this way.

Comment: What's in `$images_selected` variable? post your query please.

Comment: have two different sql statements, then. one with images table joined in, one without.

Comment: Its just a radio button saying if the user wants images or not to be displayed, in this post, I assumed the user said yes for images

Answer (score 0):

This should get your started

```
select * from
post pp
join user uu on p.user_id=uu.user_id
left join image mg on mg.post_id=pp.post_id
```

The above gives me all posts regardless of image or not

-- To exclude images, add the following

```
where mg.post_id is null
```

Query without table aliases

```
select * from
post 
join user on post.user_id=user.user_id
left join image on image.post_id=post.post_id
```

Comment: pp is a table alias, makes it easier to refer to table name in subsequent parts of the query